# vaex groupby agg sum of all columns for a larger dataset

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I have a dataset consisting of 1800000 rows and 45 columns
the operation that I am trying to perform is group by one column, the sum of other columns

the 1st step I did is considering data_df as my data frame  and all the columns are numeric

```
columns= data_df.column_names
df_result = df.groupby(columns,agg='sum')
```

the result is Kernal getting restarted
the RAM of the system is 32 GB
[image]

another approach that I tried

```
df=None
for col in colm:
    print("the col is ",col)
    
    if df is None:  
        df= data_df.groupby(data_df.MSISDN, agg=[vaex.agg.sum(col)])
    else:
        dfTemp= data_df.groupby(data_df.MSISDN, agg=[vaex.agg.sum(col)])
        df =df.join(dfTemp,left_on="MSISDN",right_on ="MSISDN",how ="inner",allow_duplication=True)
        del dfTemp
```

here I am able to find the sum up to 11 columns then the kernel gets restarted again
is there any other way to get the results using vaex or pandas ?

Comment: it seems like you grouped by all the columns and not just by one column
columns= data_df.column_names

- Which version of python you are using?

Comment: python version 3.7

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want but.. you can simply try:
`df.groupby('my_col').agg({col: 'sum' for col in df.column_names})` where `my_col` is the column on which you want to group. Should work for both vaex and pandas.